# Python: `from x import *` not importing everything

Tags: python, python-import

I know that `import *` is bad, but I sometimes use it for quick prototyping when I feel too lazy to type or remember the imports

I am trying the following code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *

shaders.doSomething()
```

It results in an error: `NameError: global name 'shaders' is not defined'

If I change the imports:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders

shaders.doSomething()
```

The error disappears. Why does `*` not include `shaders`?

Comment: Looks like `OpenGL.GL.shaders` is a subpackage, not an object defined in `OpenGL.GL`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/64130/1265154

Comment: @sapi It is a shaders.py file, so it is a module?

Comment: Yes it is. It's a module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shaders` is a submodule, not a function.

The syntax `from module import something` doesn't import submodules (Which, as another answer stated, not defined in `__all__`).

To take the module, you'll have to import it specifically:

```
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
```

Or, if you only want to have a few functions of `shaders`:

```
from OpenGL.Gl.shaders import function1, function2, function3
```

And if you want to have all the functions of `shaders`, use:

```
from OpenGL.Gl.shaders import *
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting... then how come doing something like `from urllib import *` imports the `parse` submodule, but not the other submodules, like `request`?

Comment: It could be that `parse` is included in `__all__`, see the answer just below >

Answer (score 11):

If `shaders` is a submodule and [it’s not included in `__all__`](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), `from … import *` won’t import it.

[And yes, it is a submodule.](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/pydoc/OpenGL.GL.shaders.html)

Comment: which file (or folder) should  `__all__` be within?

Answer (score 0):

I learned this from my own situation. A module did not automatically import along with the rest of the package. Before that experience my mistaken understanding was that every packages's modules automatically import from an `import x` or a `from x import *`.  They don't.

Beginners might expect EVERYTHING to import under those calls, I believe. But the following GUI programming code, which is common, demonstrates that that's not the case:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
```

In the above example, module `ttk` doesn't import automatically along with the rest of the `tkinter` package, for instance.

The explanation that I've been told is as follows: when you use `from x import *`, you actually only imported things in `your-python-location/lib/x/__init__.py`

Packages are folders.  Modules are files.  If the import calls for specific files then the package folder's `__init_.py` will enumerate the specific files to import.