# From module import * is not importing my functions

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I am trying to understand how to import code from one file to another. I have two files `file1.py` and `file2.py`. I am running code in the first file, and have many variables and functions defined in the second file. I am using `from file2 import *` to import the code into `file1.py`. I have no problem using variables defined in `file2.py` in `file1.py`, but with functions I am getting `NameError: name 'myfunc' is not defined` when I try to use the function in `file1.py`. I can fix this problem by writing `from file2 import myfunc`, but I thought writing `*` would import everything from that file. What is the difference for functions versus variables?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883870/python-from-x-import-not-importing-everything

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to recreate the setup you have described and it is working OK for me. Hopefully this will give you an idea of how to get it to work.

```
# file1.py #####################################
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/neko/test/")
import file2
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file2.testfunc()

# file2.py ######################################
testvar = 'hello'
def testfunc(): print testvar
```

For this test I was using python version 2.6.6

Both file1.py and file2.py is in /home/neko/test/